# How to get rid of blank space around the wrapper?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, wrapper

I am a newbie in creating web sites, and this one is for my friend. I am using Dreamweaver CS4. I can't figure it out how to get rid of blank space making a white border around my web site. Kindly advise! Here is the print screen of the web (I have not uploaded it yet):
[print screen](http://oi41.tinypic.com/29xw3yx.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Saher H. Paracha</title>
<style type="text/css">
a:link {
COLOR: #F0F;
}
a:visited {
COLOR: #FFF;
}
a:hover {
COLOR: #FFF;
}
a:active {
COLOR: #FFF;
}
<!--

#wrapper {
width: 1250px;
background-color: #FFF;
background-image: url(total-BGgif.gif);
background-attachment: scroll;
}
#left {
width: 25%;
float: left;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 13pt;
color: #999;
}
#content {
width: 50%;
float: left;
}
#right {
float: right;
width: 23%;
}
#footer {
width: 100%;
clear: both;
background-color: #DE39D8;
}
#header {
width: 100%;
}
#menu {
width: 100%;
}
#wrapper #menu table tr td {
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12pt;
font-weight: bold;
color: #C39;
}
#wrapper #left table tr td {
text-align: left;
}
#wrapper #content table tr td p {
font-size: 12pt;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
#header_space {
height: 5%;
width: 100%;
}
#wrapper #right table tr td {
text-align: center;
}
#wrapper #footer table tr td {
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
}
#wrapper #content table {
color: #DE39D8;
}
#wrapper #left table tr td a {
color: #FFF;
}
#wrapper #left table tr td a strong {
color: #DE39D8;
}
#wrapper #content table tr td p {
color: #666;
}
#wrapper #header table {
text-align: center;
}
-->
</style>
```

Comment: Please clarify the problem, it's unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you need to reset the `border` CSS property of either `html` or `body` to `0`:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Put CSS

```
html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the html selector, try it with the body.

include following code in your css:

```
    body{height: 100%; margin 0}
```

If it doesn't work, try adding !important (usually try to avoid using !important), eventually also set the border to 0

```
    body{height 100% !important;
         margin: 0 !important;
    }
```

if you would post your code it would be easier to reproduce your problem and resolve it...

Comment: code added for further assistance! I seem to be putting margin and padding settings on the wrong place

Comment: So you added the code written above to your css file just before the #wrapper and it didn't work?
And did you check in the developers console (ctrl+shift+j in chrome) where the problem could be?